# invalid operands to binary expression when using std::replace c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector that contains usernames and passwords. I am trying to do a "reset new password" function whereby I first search for the username in the vector whether the username existed,
and then next the user will be prompt to key in the new password and the old password will be replaced by the new one.

but I am encountering this error

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('User' and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')
```

Because of this line.

```
replace(userDetails.begin(), userDetails.end(), oldPassword, newPassword);
```

part of my codes related to the problem

```
string name;
cout << "Please enter a user name that the password will be reset \n";
cin >> name;

for (int i =0; i<userDetails.size(); i++) {
    if (userDetails[i].getUserName() == name) {
        string newPassword;
        string oldPassword;
        oldPassword = userDetails[i].getPassword();
        cout << "Please enter a new password" << endl;
        cin >> newPassword;
        replace(userDetails.begin(), userDetails.end(), oldPassword, newPassword);
        cout << userDetails[i].getPassword();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I should do to achieve my desired results. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Try to rename your `*Password` variables to `foo` and `bar`. Does the offending line still replaces the same thing as before? Looking at the actual documentation for `std::replace` could also help.

Answer (score 2):

**The first problem** is in the line

```
replace(userDetails.begin(), userDetails.end(), oldPassword, newPassword);
```

you are trying to replace `User` object with `std::string` object.

**The second problem** (as mentioned by **n.m.**) — you don't need to use range-based functions (`replace()` or other) inside the loop when you have your hands on the proper `User` object already.

You can use `std::find_if()` function to find the `User` object with proper name instead of writing the loop. In C++11 it's possible like this:

```
auto user = find_if(userDetails.begin(), userDetails.end(),
                   [&name](const User& u){return u.getUserName()==name;});
```

In pre C++11 code you'll need a separate predicate function instead of lambda / your own search loop (just `break;` when the user is found).

If the user is found you can set the password:

```
if(user != userDetails.end()){
    // (ask for the new password here)
    user->setPassword(newPassword); // assuming you have a setter for password field
}
```

Comment: You want to find all users which have the same password X and force them all to use a new password Y, right? That's a refreshingly novel approach to security, but probably not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was more interested in approach, not in details. Editing :)

Comment: I mean, there are two separate issues here, one is using an explicit loop to find a record (not an error per se, just not toeing the party line, not a BFD); and the second one is using `std::replace` without adequate realization of what should be replaced and where. This second issue should be corrected first, without diverting attention to anything else, because it is such a gross error, then perhaps use an std algorithm to correct the first. Trying to put it into an answer of my own, but it takes more time than I can afford now...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `userDetails` container holds `User` objects, yet you are treating it as if it contained `std::string`s. You should be replacing the password of `userDetails[i]`. How to do that depends on the details of the `User` class.

You probably want something like this, using [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable predicate to find the first user with username equal to `name`:

```
// find the right User
auto it = std::find_if(userDetails.begin(),
                       userDetails.end(),
                       [&name](const User& user) 
                       { return user.getUserName() == name;})
```

then replace the password for that user:

```
if (it != userDetails.end()) {
  // we found a user with username == name
  it->setPasswd(newPasswd);
} else
  // no user found with that username
  std::cout << "User " << name << " not found" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: so you mean that I shouldn't use vector that holds Objects but just a normal vector that holds strings rather?

Comment: @user2947249 No, just replace the passwords in the relevant objects.

Comment: do you mind showing an example? Sorry I am not very good in c++. still at beginner stage

Comment: The word "replace" doesn't necessarily mean you should use an algorithm of the std::replace family. Just say "change a password", or "set a new password" and see if it makes more sense. You already have the user record you want to change the password for, how do you proceed? Not by going back to the list of all users...

Comment: @n.m. ok. if I am not wrong. I guess you are trying to say that,my function(changing a passowrd) doesn't mean that I will have to use std::replace() method. perhaps it could be done by declaring a simple mutator e.g userDetails[i].setPassword(newPassword); to get the results I wanted?